# Как правильно сохранить PDF файл в storage в Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, storage, dompdf

Я генерирую html файл в pdf через dompdf пакет.

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadView('user.reports.pdf', compact('transactionsByDays'));
$fileName = 'transactions-'.time();
Storage::put('public/pdf/'.$fileName.'.pdf', $pdf->output());
```

Делаю я это в очереди, которую вызываю из контроллера. Но вот когда я скачиваю этот сохраненный файл потом из другого метода контроллера через `return Storage::download('public/pdf/'.$fileName.'.pdf');` у меня скачивается "поломанный" файл как на скрине 1.
В то же время если тот же код вызвать не из Job файла(очереди), а из контроллера:

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadView('user.reports.pdf', compact('transactionsByDays'));
$fileName = 'transactions-'.time();
Storage::put('public/pdf/'.$fileName.'.pdf', $pdf->output());
return Storage::download('public/pdf/'.$fileName.'.pdf');
```

То файл скачивается и отображается как надо (скрин 2).

По моим наблюдением проблема случается на этапе сохранения файла, а не на этапе скачивания. Не могу никак понять почему из контроллера все нормально сохраняется, а из джоба нет. Права на папку storage уже на 777 поставил, не помогло. Решил может стоит линк в паблик прописать, кто его знает... Но тоже мимо.

Я в полном замешательстве... В чем блин может быть проблема? Уже что-только не перепробовал, генерить респонс с заголовками типа контент-тайп аппликейшен джейсон и т.п. Все равно из джоба сохраняется поломанный файл какой-то... И ошибок никаких не следует, логи пустые. А без очередей обходиться не хочется, сами понимаете.

[image: некорректное отображение(скрин1)]

[image: корректное отображение(скрин2)]

Comment: Во вьюшке используются передаваемые переменные? Если да, вы проверили что они передаются и в том, и в другом вызовах? На первый взгляд похоже на проблему получения данных во ней во время препроцессинга.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, да, используется та, которая в compact transactionsByDays. В джобе тоже дампил ее, с ней все норм. А передаю я ее как обычно это делается, через публичный метод, который в конструкторе заполняю. В общем с этим все хорошо

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, как можно заметить, на 1 скрине заголовок "Transactions" даже не посередине отображается, как должен... Хотя у него во вьюшке text-center класс прописан

Comment: Job (возможно) выполняется из контекста консольного приложения, а не веб, так что вполне возможно там отсутствуют некоторые настройки или данные, используемые во вьюшке. Проверьте значения переменных и залогируйте их в Log::info из самой вьюшки.

Comment: Ларка при формировании шаблонов кэширует версии, попробуйте почистить весь кэш через php artisan cache:clear, и в дополнение посмотрите по проекту сами файлы кэша для этого блейда (они обычно обзываются рандомным хэшом). По этой причине может не тот файл браться при формированиии файла.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , я поставил dd во вьюшке и снова попробовал сделать тоже самое сначала из контроллера, а потом из джоба. В обоих случаях переменная оказалась заполнена нужными данными

Comment: @radar4ick постоянно прописываю optimize и cache:clear) уже за привычку взял) не помогает в данном случае :(

Comment: @radar4ick , удалил все кеш файлы - тоже не помогло

Comment: Видимо вам всё же придется переключить ваши задачи на sync режим и вручную пройтись по вьюшке с отладкой ...

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , я нашел причину. Во вьюшке я подключаю стили вот так ```<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">``` в теге head. В этом файле, который я подключаю уже лежит скомпиленные bootstrap классы и я их во вьюшке конечно же использую) но протестил class="text-center" - не работает, а style="text-align: center" - работает. Но вот только вопрос, а почему если вызывать из контроллера - то стили подгружаются, а если вызывать из джоба - не подключаются таким образом ? o_o

Comment: @DanielProtopopov и вся проблема в стилях. Так как вся таблица на бустрап классах написано - их неработоспособность и ломает pdf файл со всеми данными

Comment: Попробуйте установить [ASSET_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682748/assets-not-referencing-to-public-folder-laravel), на public/, где лежат уже скомпилированные версии файлов, и воспользоваться другими советами из этой ссылки, написав свой ответ если она вам поможет в решении вопроса.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, да, помогло. Сначала написал ASSET_URL=public/ - всё поломалось. Там нужно полный путь прописывать. Потом написал путь до своего приложения ```ASSET_URL=http://myapp.test/``` - уже ничего не поломалось, но public там писать не нужно, ведь public уже подразумевается. Но что я понял - трогать нужно было не ASSET_URL, а ```APP_URL``` , которую я так и не менял сначала проекта. В ней было написано ```http://localhost``` , а не реальный мой путь до приложения. После того как исправил эту APP_URL, PDF файл стал как надо отображаться из джобов)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , но меня всё же мучает вопрос почему проблема возникала только при использовании очереди, а в других случаях обычных HTTP запросов всё работало хорошо

Comment: Видимо как раз из-за того что для задач не доступно веб-окружение (как для контроллеров), и они вынуждены делать вызовы к URL напрямую через APP_URL.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , ну, видимо так) Как я счастлив, что решилось наконец)) А то я там для очередок и броадкаст написал, и ехо на фронте настроил, и пушер аккаунт зарегал... Не хотелось от всего этого отказываться)) И спасибо большое за помощь!